# Rails 3 Facebook user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, activerecord

What is the best way to model a Facebook user using ActiveRecord in Rails 3? As an id field is automatically created, how can I get rid of the auto_increment on this and populate this with the fb_id of each user? I also need to change the type from int so that it can store larger values required by Facebook.

Does anyone have a de facto method of doing this? I imagine this must be quite a common implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default primary field (id) like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users, :primary_key => 'facebook_id' do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "facebook_id"
end
```

EDIT: However, do you really need to get rid of the id field? Chances are you'll need it some time. Also, you should consider using OmniAuth if you're looking for 3rd-party authentication solutions (like Facebook): https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to keep having the default id provided by Rails, and adding the following:

```
class AddUIDandProviderandTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :UID, :string
    add_column :users, :provider, :string
    add_column :users, :token, :string
  end

  def down
   #
  end
end
```

By doing this, you will be able to add other external auth systems into your users table, and not just rely on Facebook.

Remember to store the **UID** as a string.